# array of object in php but different way

Tags: php, arrays, object

i have this piece of code that i am not able to understand:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    static $Instances = array();
    $key = "localhost:iotatut:PASSWORD:DATABASE";
    if(!isset($Instances[$key])){
        $Instances[$key] = new Database();
    }
    return $Instances[$key];
}
```

Database is the name of the class and getInstance is the name of member function. getInstance will be called from another file and database.php file is included in which the Database class is made.I want to know what will happen when if condition gets executed and suppose it is running for the very first time.. What will be $Instances[$key]=new Database();

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @harvider is this the exact code or have you just selected the bits you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right it is the Singleton pattern.

http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Creational/Singleton/README.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: i am not quite sure what exactly it is i have this file and it was working fine for me bu somehow  now my new server is using php 7 so i need to use mysqli.. that why i need to make some changes in this code.. and i ma not getting what exactly this line is doing....

Comment: @harvindersingh
I will assume that this line creates a new connection and class, if this was not done before.

Answer (score 0):

As @HouseInTheForest points out, this is a classic function for obtaining a singleton object.

You use a singleton when you want only one instance of that object to exist in your code, no matter from where you call it. Thus, you save the instance of the object in the object itself, and return the object on request. The singleton in mostly used for database connections (you don't want to setup a new connection each time you run a query) and Log classes (you want one log class, that holds all information.

Below some comments about what the code does

```
// Method to get the instance of the singleton object, by calling this method statically.  thus: $oDB = Database::getInstance();
public static function getInstance()
{
    // static variable to hold the instance of the object in
    static $Instances = array();
    // I guess this line holds the host:user:password:database to connect to the database server (mostly MySql)
    $key = "localhost:iotatut:XXXXXXXX:DATABASE";
    // If an instance with this key combination does not exist, setup a new Database object to hold the information
    if(!isset($Instances[$key])){
         $Instances[$key] = new Database();
    }
    // Return the instance to the Database object.
    return $Instances[$key];
}
```

Note: in your comment you are refering to mysqli. As of PHP 7 `mysql` is removed and you HAVE to use php mysqli. The whole class needs to be updated, meaning that every line with mysql_XXXX (e.g. `mysql_connect`, `mysql_query`, etc) needs to be updated to `mysqli_connect`, `mysqli_query` etc. Furthermore, you need to provide the connection with each call... If you don't know what you're doing, ask a programmer.